# How to make a list of lists from values of primary lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following four lists:

```
w= [1,2,3]
x= [4,5,6]
y= [7,8,9]
z= [10,11,12]
```

I need the outcome to be as follows:

```
result = [[1,4,7,10],[2,5,8,11],[3,6,9,12]]
```

what's the best way to make such a list?

Comment: `list(map(list, zip(w, x, y, z)))`

Comment: The question doesn't appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
def main():
    w= [1,2,3]
    x= [4,5,6]
    y= [7,8,9]
    z= [10,11,12]
    print map(list, zip(w, x, y, z))
```

> output : [[1, 4, 7, 10], [2, 5, 8, 11], [3, 6, 9, 12]]

Comment: The question is tagged python-3.x.

Answer (score 0):

What you want, is a transposed matrix like:

```
M = [w,x,y,z]
[[row[i] for row in M] for i in range(len(w))]

-> [[1, 4, 7, 10], [2, 5, 8, 11], [3, 6, 9, 12]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If all of the list's length are the same then:

```
result = []
for i in range(len(w)):
    result.append([w[i],x[i],y[i],z[i]])
```